# how to write a query on an association with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering if you can help me write a scope method for Rails that I'm having a little trouble completing.  I have an app where users can ask questions. The questions are classified according to both categories and tags i.e.

```
Question.rb has_many :categories 
Question.rb has_many :tags
```

When I show a question, I want to have a feature that shows similar questions. In order to do that, I was going to show other questions according to the following conditions

```
First, at least one category is the same
Second, at least one tag is the same
Third, the other question has at least one answer already.
```

In my show action of the Questions controller, after I find the question, I then get the categories and tags for it

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
categories = @question.categories
tags= @question.tags
```

The local variable categories might look like this

```
[#<Category id: 3, name: "Wills & Estates", created_at: "2013-04-10 21:53:49", updated_at: "2013-04-10 21:53:49">, #<Category id: 4, name: "Business Law", created_at: "2013-04-10 21:53:49", updated_at: "2013-04-10 21:53:49">]
```

So what I do then is strip the name out of it like this

```
cats = Question.get_categories(categories)
```

with get_categories on the Question.rb model like this

```
  def self.get_categories(categories)
    categories = categories.map(&:name)
  end
```

I do the exact same thing for tags

```
cats = Question.get_tags(tags)
```

Question.rb

```
  def self.get_tags(tags)
     tags = tags.map(&:name)   
  end
```

I then pass 'cats' and 'tags' (which are just strings of the categories and tags) into a scope on the Question.rb model

```
 @similarquestions = Question.similar_questions(cats, tags)
```

This is where I get lost...

```
 scope :similar_questions, lambda { |cats, tags|
  joins(:categories).where(:categories { :name => cats})
  joins(:tags).where(:tags { :name => tags })
 }
```

The local variable 'cats' and 'tags' might be a single string, or they might be multiple strings depending on how many categories and tags a particular question has. My criteria for locating similar questions, as stated above, is to have one category the same and one tag the same (with the question also having at least one answer).

Could you give me some pointers as to what I might do inside this scope to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I'm wondering if I should be passing arrays in as local variables and do something like

```
scope :similar_questions, lambda { |cats, tags|
      cats.each do |cat|
      joins(:categories).where(:categories { :name => cat})
      end 
      tags.each do |tag|
      joins(:tags).where(:tags { :name => tag })
      end
     }
```

but even then I'm having trouble figuring out a way to achieve what I'm trying to do. One of my concerns is that I don't want a maze of if/then clauses in the scope. I'm sure there's a tidier way to do what I want, but I can't figure it out. One of the reasons I thought of passing in an array was to check if something was 'in' the array etc.

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Update

```
Question.rb has_many :answers
```

Comment: What determines if a question was answered - is there an `Answer` model that `belongs_to` a `Question`?

Comment: @PinnyM yes, that's right. Should have mentioned that. Question has_many :answers

Comment: Do `Category` and `Tag` belong_to a `Question` or is this a many-to-many relationship through a join model (or habtm)?

Comment: @PinnyM  Question.rb has_many :categories, and Question.rb has_many :tags, with those models also obviously,  belong_to :question

Comment: So you aren't sharing category and tag records among various questions; rather, the categories and tags are considered similar to each other if their names are similar.  Correct?  If so, the answer below should work for you.

Comment: @PinnyM yes, if a category has the same name, it will be considered in the same category. Users select a category (from a choice of 7) when they make a question, and then create their own tags. For example, a category might be 'Family Law' and a tag would be 'divorce' to help refine it. However, I commented on your answer explaining that the method's not working for me. It's saying 'undefined' method categories for the local variable question. Not sure why that is, because, as noted in OP, I can call categories on question.categories as as result of the association. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :similar_questions, lambda {|question|
  joins(:categories, :tags).includes(:answers).
  where( categories: {name: question.categories.pluck(:name)},
         tags: {name: question.tags.pluck(:name)} ).
  where("questions.id != ? AND answers.id IS NOT NULL", question.id)
}
```

Now you can do:

```
@similar_questions = Question.similar_questions(self)
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better if using the ids like `( categories: {id: question.categories.pluck(:id)},
           tags: {id: question.tags.pluck(:id)} )`?

Comment: The `id` wouldn't quite match the name, but you're right that the `id` would be a better fit for the lookup - if they shared common tags through a join model.  Updated to use `pluck`, as you noted.

Comment: I'm getting an 'undefined method' error for question.categories in the third line of your method. The same would probably also happen for question.tags (if the app didn't crash before it got to that line). I'm not sure why this is happening. In the controller, I can call @question.categories (as I noted in my OP).

Comment: If you are calling it from the view, then change `Question.similar_questions(self)` to `Question.similar_questions(@question)`

Comment: Actually, I'm calling it from the controller. 'self' in the controller is not the instance of the question. I had to pass in the instance of the question Question.similar_questions(@question). Works great, except for one small issue. It's including the instance of the question as one of the results, because obviously the category and tags are the same. For example, question.id of 57 will return itself from that scope. Is there an easy way to include that in the scope? If not, I'll just do a check for it in the view.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Leahcim, good point about the original question - updated to filter that out.